# Why isn't this recursive definition of reduce working (JS)?

Tags: javascript, recursion, reduce

I'm attempting to redefine Javascript's reduce using a recursive function.
Here's my attempt, which doesn't work.  If anyone can change it only slightly to make it work, that would be great because I'd understand it better.  (This is an exercise in [functional-javascript-workshop](https://github.com/timoxley/functional-javascript-workshop)).

```
function reduce(arr, fn, initial) {
  if (arr.length) {
    var newArr = arr.slice(1, arr.length);
    return reduce(newArr, fn, fn(arr[0]));
  } else {
    return initial;
  }
}

module.exports = reduce
```

It gives me the following cryptic error message, which I don't know how to interpret:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/functional-javascript-workshop/exercises/basic_recursion/exercise.js:13
    prev[curr] = ++prev[curr] || 1
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot create property 'undefined' on string 'exercitation'
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/functional-javascript-workshop/exercises/basic_recursion/exercise.js:13:29
    at reduce (/home/david/node-school/functional-workshop/solution.js:7:28)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/functional-javascript-workshop/exercises/basic_recursion/exercise.js:12:10
    at obtainResult (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/functional-javascript-workshop/exercises/runner.js:100:21)
    at Exercise.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/functional-javascript-workshop/exercises/runner.js:66:27)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/functional-javascript-workshop/node_modules/workshopper-exercise/exercise.js:188:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/functional-javascript-workshop/node_modules/workshopper-exercise/exercise.js:195:7
    at Exercise.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/functional-javascript-workshop/exercises/runner.js:34:5)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/functional-javascript-workshop/node_modules/workshopper-exercise/exercise.js:188:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/functional-javascript-workshop/node_modules/workshopper-exercise/exercise.js:195:7
```

Comment: Just wondering: does `if(arr.length)` work? I always use `if(arr.length > 0)`...

Comment: You aren't showing us the correct code. The error is occurring in `exercise.js` after being called in your `solution.js` at line 7.

Comment: @Danmoreng, it tests the truthy value

Comment: What is `fn`? Should `initial` be the `index` of element in array?

Comment: @guest271314  fn is any function that will be used for reducing the array

Comment: @guest271314  initial is the initial object, which is optional for js's reduce but I assume it is given

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to update the accumulator:

```js
function reduce(arr, fn, acc) {
  if (arr.length) {
    var newArr = arr.slice(1, arr.length);
    acc = fn(arr[0], acc) 
    return reduce(newArr, fn, acc);
  } else {
    return acc;
  }
}

console.log(reduce([1,2,3], (val, sum) => sum + val, 0))
```

Comment: the dude abides

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to pass the current value of the accumulator, i.e. `initial`, into the `fn` call.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, you missed passing the accumulator to `fn`. If you're curious, `reduce` can be expressed in a single ternary (`?:`) expression – also, `arr.slice(1)` will slice from `1` to the end of the array; there's no need to specify the end of the slice in this case

```js
const reduce = (arr, fn, acc) =>
  arr.length === 0
    ? acc
    : reduce(arr.slice(1), fn, fn(acc, arr[0]))

const add = (x,y) => x + y

console.log(reduce([1,2,3], add, 0)) // 6
```

Because `arr.length === 0`, `arr.slice(1)` and `arr[1]` are so common in functional code dealing with arrays, it's common to see these abstracted into functions to reduce complexity and cognitive load

```js
// isEmpty :: [a] -> Boolean
const isEmpty = arr => arr.length === 0

// head :: [a] -> a
const head = arr => arr[0]

// tail :: [a] -> [a]
const tail = arr => arr.slice(1)

// reduce :: ([a], ((b, a) -> b), b) -> b
const reduce = (arr, fn, acc) =>
  isEmpty(arr)
    ? acc
    : reduce(tail(arr), fn, fn(acc, head(arr)))

// add :: (Number, Number) -> Number
const add = (x,y) => x + y

console.log(reduce([1,2,3], add, 0)) // 6
```